# URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 24] Too many open files>

Tags: python, scrapy, urllib2

I'm using scrapy on a dedicated server and I have this error lot of times :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
  File "dirbot/spiders/expired.py", line 54, in errback_httpbin
  File "dirbot/spiders/expired.py", line 65, in checkDomain
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1227, in http_open
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 24] Too many open files>
```

I already add this configuration but I still have this error.

> at /etc/sysctl.conf
>
> add:
>
> ```
> net.core.somaxconn=131072
> fs.file-max=131072
> ```
>
> and then:
>
> ```
> sudo sysctl -p
> ```
>
> at /usr/include/linux/limits.h
>
> change:
>
> ```
> NR_OPEN = 65536
> ```
>
> at /etc/security/limits.conf
>
> add:
>
> ```
> *                soft    nofile          65535
> *                hard    nofile          65535
> ```

Can someone help me to fix that ?

**Update,
My configuration Scrapy :**

```
custom_settings = {
    'RETRY_ENABLED': False,
    'DEPTH_LIMIT' : 0,
    'DEPTH_PRIORITY' : 1,
    'LOG_ENABLED' : False,
    'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN' : 64,
    'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS' : 128,
    'REACTOR_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE' : 30,
    'COOKIES_ENABLED' : False,
    'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT' : 10,
    'DOWNLOAD_WARNSIZE' : 66554432
}
```

Comment: I guess you could also spawn multiple scrapy processes?

Comment: I already do that ! I'm using scrapyd

Comment: How many website do you try to scrape concurrently?

Comment: I would suggest posting some of your code to configure the spider.

Comment: I updated my post with the scrapy configuration.
I'm using 4 crawlers at the same time. (4 websites).